# ubuntu 20.04 add static route without netplan

Tags: networking, 20.04

I want to add static routes, I am aware I can do this with netplan but its creating a new network connection every time I try it. I have a wired connection and it creates another along side it in network manager and activates it which means the active connection is not the one the vpn is using and that means no internet access. You can see why its a problem.

What I am trying to achieve.
connect to my vpn provider whilst also being able to local resources without disconnecting the vpn. My router does not allow me to connect to a local hosted locally by its fqdn and the vpn does not allow it by the ip. So I have an issue, I have to disconnect the vpn whenever I want to transfer files which is a lot during a dev session. and reconnect to view the changes made in a browser, often i forget to (dis)connect which is a problem and takes up time.

So I have added routes via the cli route command but they are removed whenever the network reconnects. How can I add the static routes without using netplan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I can add a route from the GUI of network manager.